# How to make a heat map of grid data

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, interpolation, matrix-multiplication

I have this data with values on the edges of the matrix and other values at evenly spaced interval within the matrix. I want to predict the values of the zero positions from the original values and make a heat map of the new data. Through suggest, I use scatteredInterpolant, ndgrid and interpolant since the data is that interp2 (matlab functions) cannot be used to interpolate the zero elements. Now, this method doe not give me a smooth figure and I am want to know if someone can offer some help. I have attached the figure from my code, the data and the code to this post.Thank you.

```
[knownrows, knowncolumns, knownvalues] = find(DataGrid);  %get location and value of all non-zero points
interpolant = scatteredInterpolant(knownrows, knowncolumns, knownvalues,'linear'); %create interpolant from known values
[queryrows, querycolumns] = ndgrid(1:1:size(DataGrid, 1), 1:1:size(DataGrid, 2));  %create grid of query points
interpolatedj = interpolant(queryrows, querycolumns);
```

HeatMap(interpolatedj)

https://www.mediafire.com/?pq40x1ljxk8h996

https://www.mediafire.com/?pq40x1ljxk8h996

Answer (score 0):

To plot a smoothed matrix you can use `pcolor` and set the shading parameter to `interp`

```
pcolor(M); %where M is your 2D matrix
shading interp %set the shading to interp
```

Comment: I do still the grid of the edge in the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`image(M)` or `imagesc(M)` where M is a matrix. `pcolor(M)` also works. If your matrix is huge then you need to remove edges otherwise figure just looks like blank image.

Comment: I have tried them of and still see the grid from the edges in the plot.

Comment: how big is your matrix? if possible post your figure. use `set('EdgeColor','none')` .

Comment: The problem is with the plot function but the interpolation of my data. Can anyone suggest a good way of going about this problem?